# How to create a animated GIF image in a single step?

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I was just trying out to create a GIF image from a group of images. Then I end up with ImageMagick. I have posted the code as answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a GIF image from a group of images through command prompt, you can do it with ImageMagick in a single step.

```
 "convert   -delay 20   -loop 0   image_to_convert*.jpg   new_animated.gif"
```

For example,

If names of the images starts with 'sphere' and ends with '.jpg'. Executing the following command we can generate GIF image.

```
"convert   -delay 20   -loop 0   sphere*.jpg   new_animated.gif"
```